# ListView subobject clickable confilct

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

After asking a question and spending 15 days to solve this, i  am looking for help and solution here again.
In MainActivity i have created Json Downloading Task which is downloading data from http and with CustomListAdapter.class i  populate the listview.
Everything works.
Now, in the listview i have 2 textview's which i want to be clickable, one of them is "Accept", that textview is just in xml it's not populated with Adapter or Json.
"Accept" should work like this "Change the text to Accepted and change color" and its working like everything else. BUT when i click on first "Accept"(Position 0) in listview
it changes other listview items (Position 4,9). It's like i clicked textviews on Position 4,9. 
On first image is before clicking the "Accept" and second on is afer clicking.

[image: before clicking]
///
[image: after clicking]

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected static final String TAG = null;
public ArrayList<FeedItem> feedList;
public ListView feedListView;
private ProgressBar progressbar;
 private CustomListAdapter adap;
 private LayoutInflater mInflater;


@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
      feedListView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);

      mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      String url = "...";
      new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url);

      getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.angel);
      progressbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


       public void updateList() {
    adap = new CustomListAdapter(this, feedList);

           feedListView.setAdapter(adap);

            }


      public class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {


      ///....
```

CustomListAdapter.class

```
    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  
 {

private ArrayList<FeedItem> listData;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> data;
protected ListView feedListView;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FeedItem> listData)
{
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mContext = context;
    data = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        data.add("Sample Text " + String.valueOf(i));
    }
}


@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}


public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
 final ViewHolder holder;
 View row=convertView;
    if ((row == null) || (row.getTag()==null)) {

     convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
     holder = new ViewHolder();
     holder.headlineView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
     holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.confid);
     holder.accept= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.acceptTV);

     convertView.setTag(holder);



    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

   final FeedItem newsItem = (FeedItem) listData.get(position);
    holder.accept.setFocusable(true);

    holder.accept.setClickable(true);
    holder.headlineView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getTitle()));
    holder.reportedDateView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getContent()));

    holder.accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


                    holder.accept.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsItem.getContent()));
        }
    });



    return convertView;
}




static class ViewHolder
{

    TextView accept;
    TextView headlineView;
    TextView reportedDateView;
    ImageView imageView;
    FeedItem newsItem;

}
```

Comment: remove holder and then use

Comment: only for "Accept" textview or for all?

Comment: @Rohit why is ViewHolder a problem?

Comment: because i also face this problem then it solved by removing view holder

Comment: @Rohit i don't think that is the problem. also it is recommended to use view holder pattern

Comment: @SandraMladenovic try using `setTag` an `getTag`

Comment: @Raghunandan i tried via tags i tried so many  things i don't even remember

Comment: @SandraMladenovic You want the changes permanently?

Comment: No, it can be lost when swiching to next page. The "Accept" button should send data to json server. Some kind of vote up button

Comment: @SandraMladenovic set the tag on the textView as well, and in the tag set the position.  Now on click event callback, get the tag attached with the clicked view. And on this tagged position, do your task

Comment: @GauravGupta i tried that couple of times...

Comment: 1 time try without holder then see

Comment: @Rohit can you post a answer again without holder?

Comment: but they post negtive votes

Comment: @SandraMladenovic check my post and give it a try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to understand how listview recycle mechanism works

[How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

Use a Model Class. Assume you already have the below

```
public class FeedItem {

String title,content;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

}
```

In `getView`

```
holder.accept.setText(listData.get(position).getContent()); 
holder.accept.setTag(position);
holder.accept.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
```

Then

```
private OnClickListener mClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
    FeedItem newsItem = (FeedItem) listData.get(pos);
    newsItem.setContent("Accepted");
    CustomListadapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
};
```

Exaplanation :

You use a model class which has getters and setters.

You `setTag` to the button with position. In onClick you get the tag ie position and change the content accordingly. You refresh listview by calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter.

For the benefit of others here's a example

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   ArrayList<Holder> list = new ArrayList<Holder>();
   ListView lv;
   CustomListAdapter cus;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            Holder h = new Holder();
            h.setTitle("Title"+i);
            h.setContent("Content"+i);
            h.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            list.add(h);
        }
        cus = new CustomListAdapter(this,list);
        lv.setAdapter(cus);
    }
}
```

Model class Holder

```
public class Holder {

    String title,content;
    int color;

    public int getColor() {
return color;

    public void setColor(int color) {
this.color = color;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

CustomListAdapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<Holder> list;
    public CustomListAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<Holder> list) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mainActivity);
        this.list =list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        ViewHolder holder; 
        if (convertView == null) { 
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, 
                    parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(); 
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
            holder.b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
           convertView.setTag(holder); 
       } else { 
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
       } 
       Holder h = list.get(position);
       holder.tv.setText(h.getTitle());
       holder.b.setText(h.getContent());
       holder.b.setTextColor(h.getColor());
       holder.b.setOnClickListener(mClickListener); 
       holder.b.setTag(position);
       return convertView; 
}
     private OnClickListener mClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Holder h = (Holder) list.get(pos);
                h.setContent("Accepted");
                    h.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                CustomListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            };
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView tv;
        Button b;
    }
}
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap

Button at row 1 and 5 is clicked so it is changed to Accepted and is Blue.

[image]

Comment: THAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! after 15 days.... you are Angel!

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan , i have also changed in my app, and +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

```
getView(...){
if ((row == null) || (row.getTag()==null)) {
 // some code
}else{
 // some code
}
holder.accept.setTag(position);

// some more code

if(newsItem.isSelected()){
holder.accept.setText("accepted");
}else{
holder.accept.setText("accept");
}

//handling click
holder.accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                int position = (Integer)arg0.getTag();
                // change backing dataset here instead.
                FeedItem m = listData.get(position);
                // declare a boolean 'selected' in FeedItem 
                // toggle the previous selection
                m.setSelected(! m.isSelected());
                // call notifydatasetChanged
                CustomListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
});

// some more code
}


class FeedItem{
// some data member

boolean selected = false;
public boolean isSelected(){
return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean status){
selected = status;
}
}
```

Comment: this is correct. FeetItem is model class. but you got to change the data

Comment: @Raghunandan here, i am changing the selection status and setting is to true. Or,i think toggling the status would be better idea.

Comment: op was to set text to the button so instead of toggling change the button settext. any way this will work for changing text also

Comment: Please also add Model class

Comment: @Rohit This model class is defined by OP. This is simple java class which would be having some member depending on user's use case. Adding simple version of Model class in code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes surely from the fact that you don't reset the state of views when they are reused. ListView reused views for better memory management. So adapt your `getView()` to adapt the text and color according to the selected state of the item. I didn't see where you keep it inside your code actually so I cannot give you a working example.

Something like

```
    if (newsItem.selected)
      holder.accept.setText("accepted");
    else
      holder.accept.setText("accept");
```