# Maintain scroll position in nested RecyclerViews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, nestedrecyclerview

I have a `ViewHolder` that contains another `RecyclerView`. This type of the `ViewHolder` gets reused multiple times.

Since the `ViewHolder` is shared between different items, the scroll position of the `RecyclerView` is also shared between items. Eg, You scroll to the end of the first item, the fifth item's RecyclerView also gets scrolled to the very end, because the view is reused.

I'm trying to solve this by mapping 1 `ViewHolder` to 1 item.

I've tried to set an `itemId` for the item, call [RecyclerView.ViewHolder#setIsRecyclable(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#setIsRecyclable(boolean)), and extend/set `RecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews()` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34900944/1127180)

After I scroll down and scroll back up (The `ViewHolder` gets recycled), the scroll position of the inner RecyclerView is reset to the first item.

Comment: The only solution I found is to store the LayoutManager state(onSaveInstanceState)  to the model during onRecycle event, and try to restore(onRestoreInstanceState) the layout manager state in bind method.