# Change the icon of one row of a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I am displaying some rows in my `ListView` and want to change only one of the row, by seeing if any of the date in the list matches today's date.

My partial code is:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE, LLLL d", Locale.US);
String[] suspendedDates = {
    "Tuesday, January 1",
    "Wednesday, April 16",
    "Monday, October 6",
    "Wednesday, December 25"
};

lvDisplay = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDisp);

        for (int i = 0; i < suspendedDates.length; i ++) {
            sDate = suspendedDates[i];
            sReason = datesReason[i];
            if (Arrays.asList(suspendedDates).contains(df.format(Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getTime()))) {
                inIconShow = R.drawable.caliconpressed; //if today matches display a different drawable
                contents.add(new SetRows(inIconShow, sDate, sReason));
            }
            if (!Arrays.asList(suspendedDates).contains(df.format(Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getTime()))) {
                inIconShow = R.drawable.calicon; //if today doesn't match the array display the default drawable
                contents.add(new SetRows(inIconShow, sDate, sReason));
            }
        }
        // Now set your adapter.
        adapter = new SetRowsCustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listdates, contents);
        lvDisplay.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`SetRowsCustomAdapter` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SetRowsCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SetRows> {
    Context context;
   int layoutResourceId;
   ArrayList<SetRows> data=new ArrayList<SetRows>();
   public SetRowsCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<SetRows> data) {
       super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
       this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
       this.context = context;
       this.data = data;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View row = convertView;
       ImageHolder holder = null;

       if(row == null)
       {
           LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
           row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

           holder = new ImageHolder();
           holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvDateVal);
           //holder.txtTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/robm.ttf"));
           holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon0);
           holder.txtID = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvReasonVal);
           //holder.txtID.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/robm.ttf"));
           row.setTag(holder);
       }
       else
       {
           holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
       }

       SetRows myImage = data.get(position);
       holder.txtTitle.setText(myImage.name);
       holder.txtID.setText(myImage.id);
       int outImage=myImage.image;
       holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(outImage);
      return row;

   }

   static class ImageHolder
   {
       ImageView imgIcon;
       TextView txtTitle;
       TextView txtID;
   }
}
```

So the 4th row should have a different icon and the other 3 should have default icon. What is happening is if the date matches, every row has the different icon, otherwise every row has the default icon.

How do I fix it?

Comment: post code in `SetRowsCustomAdapter` class

Comment: Update my question to show the adapter class

Comment: post your model class (SetRows) code and how you populate arraylist.

Comment: @Raghunandan I remember you. You helped a LOT last time. I think I have fixed the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want change the image you can do in `getView` method like bellow code:

```
@Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View row = convertView;
       ImageHolder holder = null;

       if(row == null)
       {
           LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
           row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

           holder = new ImageHolder();
           holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvDateVal);
           //holder.txtTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/robm.ttf"));
           holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon0);
           holder.txtID = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvReasonVal);
           //holder.txtID.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/robm.ttf"));
           row.setTag(holder);
       }
       else
       {
           holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
       }

       SetRows myImage = data.get(position);
       holder.txtTitle.setText(myImage.name);
       holder.txtID.setText(myImage.id);
       int outImage=myImage.image;
       if (data.getValue)
          holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(deferentIcon);
       else
          holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(defaultIcon);
      return row;

   }
```

and if you want change multi row icons you can send one list of your row and check in that, and for refresh you list use **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**

**Edit**

for your situation you can add on boolean value in your DS and if date equal set true otherwise set else that and in if statement check that

Comment: It doesn't have to be the 4th position, I want to match the date only. If today's date matches any of the date mentioned in the `suspendedDates`, then display a different icon.

Comment: you can check with every thing that you want, just set your condition in if statement in getView method

Comment: See my Edit, add one boolean value to data DS or check date in getView Method

Comment: I did the check inside the adapter as you recommended but a little differently and it worked!!! Thanks.

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan one point worth noting listview recycles views. so change getView accordingly. so this may not work well.

Comment: i dont get Your mean @Raghunandan, can you edit my post as you wish.thanks for useful comment. my english word is not good,sorry

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611123/listview-subobject-clickable-confilct/20612237#20612237. here only those row buttons that are clicked are updated which is similar to op's case is what i meant. If it works for OP its fine

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan so this `if (position == 4)
          holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(deferentIcon);` might not work well is what i wanted to point out.

Comment: @Raghunandan i told to OP that create one boolean value in SetRows class and change that every time that want, i got your mean

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43888/discussion-between-shayan-pourvatan-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 0):

Use viewHolder in adapter then use notifyDataSetChanged() in adapter; 
I already used and it will help.