# Android List View Item repeated

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

While  working on list view and finding a problem after inflating list item to view using custom adapter.
My problem is a random list item view button text in changed to "Added" instead of displaying text "Add",i have added my adapter code -

```
view = convertView;
if(view==null){
   view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
   mHolder = new ListHolder();
   mHolder.mNameTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_full_name);
   mHolder.mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
   view.setTag(mHolder);
}
else{
     mHolder = (ListHolder) view.getTag();
}
mHolder.mNameTV.setText(myList.get(position).getName());
if(myList.get(position).isAdded()){
   mHolder.mButton.setText("Added");
}
 else{
      mHolder.mButton.setText("Add");
 }
return view;
```

It display correct name in text view but value of button in list item is not correct.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611123/listview-subobject-clickable-confilct. your case is similar to this

Comment: code seems correct.. maybe the problem is in the class that handles the data?

Comment: thedjaney Sir ,i have debug code multiple times and check data flag value and found correct but at run times it dont show correct view.

Comment: any important reason to use BaseAdapter?

Comment: try creating one holder per position...

Comment: if i'm not mistaken the whole list uses one instance of the convertView.. if you create depending on view==null, they might get mixed up.

Comment: set tag to button `mHolder.mButton.setTag(position)` then replace this `if(myList.get(position).isAdded())` with if(myList.get(mHolder.mButton.getTag()).isAdded())

Comment: thedjaney Sir, i have tried creating new holder per position but still finding same problem.When i click on a single button after that 4-5 button text changed.

Comment: @ Ketan Sir, i have try as you suggested but after click ing 5th position button,multiple button text is changed in this position sequence- 5,13,21,29,37 and i have total 45 item in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying different example i have found solution to my problem.
I create two different view for it say 1.user_added.xml and 2. user_add.xml.
and inside my adapter checking condition and then inflate view like this-

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(myList.get(position).isAdded())
        return ADDED;
    else
        return NOTADDED;
}
```

and inside getView method -

```
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position); 
    if(view==null){
        mHolder = new ListHolder();
        if(viewType==NOTADDED){
           view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_not_added, parent,false);
        }
        else{
             view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_added, parent,false);
        }
        mHolder.mNameTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_full_name);
        mHolder.mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
        view.setTag(mHolder);
     }
     else{
        mHolder = (ListHolder) view.getTag();
     }
      mHolder.mNameTV.setText(myList.get(position).getName());
      mHolder.mButton.setTag(position);
      mHolder.mButton.setOnClickListener(MyListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(myList.get(position).isAdded()){
```

Here make sure that, you have not already set `true` while parsing the data. As you have used the `isAdded()` method above. It seems that, by default the value of this method is returning `true` and as a result your button text always comes as "Added".

Comment: Sir i have set default value of flag isAdded = false and after button click value of flag is updated to true.When app first run all button show value "Add" and then i click on one button then random number of button text is change to "Added".that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of recycling of ListView, so you should store the view and change the text according to the View.

Modify your code something like this,

```
if(view==null){
   view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
   mHolder = new ListHolder();
   mHolder.mNameTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_full_name);
   mHolder.mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
   view.setTag(mHolder);
   mHolder.mButton.setTag(position);
}
else{
     mHolder = (ListHolder) view.getTag();
}
mHolder.mNameTV.setText(myList.get(position).getName());
int getPosition = (Integer)mHolder.mButton.getTag();
if(myList.get(getPosition).isAdded()){
   mHolder.mButton.setText("Added");
}
 else{
      mHolder.mButton.setText("Add");
 }
```

Comment: Your code does not make any sense. Why adding the same button reference to the tag when you have it in the ViewHolder anyway?