# Buttons Missing When Scroll the ListView

Tags: android, listview

when i click the listview item, that particular item button is Visible. when i scroll the listview the buttons are gone. how to implement this functionality. what is the wrong in this please help me. Thanks

Here is My Code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    SampleAdapter sa;
    ArrayList<String> as=new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            as.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        sa=new SampleAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        lv.setAdapter(sa);

        }
    class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        Context ctx;
        Button b;
        TextView tv;
        LayoutInflater lin;
        public SampleAdapter(Context ct) {
            this.ctx=ct;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return as.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            lin=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            arg1=lin.inflate(R.layout.li, null);
            tv=(TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            b=(Button)arg1.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            tv.setText(as.get(pos));
            b.setText(as.get(pos));
            arg1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Button c=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                    c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            return arg1;
        }

    }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

li.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but here your button visibility you set `android:visibility="invisible"` and you said _particular item button is Visible_? simple remove `android:visibility="invisible"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

This makes the button not visible.

And then you have

```
c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

You need to understand that listview recycles views. So when you scroll your Buttons become invisible because the views are recycled.

Check the below link

[How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

Well check this example which is very similar to yours

[ListView subobject clickable confilct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611123/listview-subobject-clickable-confilct/20612237#20612237)

TO fix you can use a Model class

Model class

```
public class Model {
int visibility;
 String value;


public int getVisibility() {
    return visibility;
}
public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
    this.visibility = visibility;
}
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    SampleAdapter sa;
    final int visible1 = View.INVISIBLE;
    final int visible2 = View.VISIBLE;
    ArrayList<Model> as=new ArrayList<Model>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            Model model  = new Model();
            model.setValue(String.valueOf(i));
            model.setVisibility(visible1);
            as.add(model);
        }
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        sa=new SampleAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        lv.setAdapter(sa);

        }
    class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        Context ctx;
        Button b;
        TextView tv;
        LayoutInflater lin;
        public SampleAdapter(Context ct) {
            this.ctx=ct;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return as.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            lin=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            arg1=lin.inflate(R.layout.fg, null);
            tv=(TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            b=(Button)arg1.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            tv.setText(as.get(pos).getValue());
            b.setText(as.get(pos).getValue());
            arg1.setTag(pos);
            b.setVisibility(as.get(pos).getVisibility());
            arg1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int pos = (int) v.getTag();
                    Model model = as.get(pos);
                    model.setVisibility(visible2);
                    SampleAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
            return arg1;
        }

    }
    }
```

Snap

You can scroll up and down and the state remains

[image]

Comment: No..User has scroll problem..he wants to display buttons after the click on the item..thats working fine..but when he scroll He needs to maintain the the postions of visible items.

Comment: @kalyanpvs posted a example also at first glance i misread the post

Comment: now its perfect..this is what i want to say..+1 from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this in your adapter:

```
arg1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Button c=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                    c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
```

and this in your `li.xml`

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

You have code that makes the button invisible by defailt in your li.xml and onItemClick in your adapter your making it visible