# android: listView items have button

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button

[image]

I have certain entries in my list view item.

when i click on Item first like button....only last item like button color value is changing.
when i click on Item second like button ....only last item like button color value is changing.
But

when i click on first item i got position = 0 and offer_id = O101

when i click on Second item i got position = 1 and offer_id = O103

when i click on third item i got position = 2 and offer_id = O104

every time when i click on any like button of any item of list view ... the like button of last item of list view color gets changed.

I want that whenever i click on any like button of list item, the like button of only that list item should change.
how to get this corrected.
This is my code....

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_list_item,
                    parent, false);
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.offer_name);
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.expiry_date);
            holder.b1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.like_button);

            holder.b2 = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.share_button);
            holder.tvoid = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.offer_id);
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.like);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final OfferItem it = item.get(position);
        holder.tv1.setText(it.getoffer_name());
        final String message = holder.tv1.getText().toString();
        holder.tv2.setText("Offer ends: " + it.getexpiry_date());
        holder.tvoid.setText(it.getoffer_id());
        holder.tv.setText("Like");
        id_offiers_list.add(it.getoffer_id());

        holder.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String offerid = id_offiers_list.get(position);
                System.out.println(offerid);
                if (clicked) {
                    System.out.println(position);
                    holder.b1
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_icon_hover);
                    holder.tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#eaa232"));
                    clicked = false;

                } else {
                    System.out.println(position);
                    holder.b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_icon);
                    holder.tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#454545"));
                    clicked = true;
                }
            }
        });

        holder.b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                facebookIntent.setType("text/plain");
                // facebookIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
                facebookIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(facebookIntent,
                        "Share..."));
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: set `background selector` to your `button`

Comment: did your changed save after scroll?

Comment: no.if i have 5 item in list view,when i click on 2 item like button.....the color value change of 4 item like button....

Comment: @Amardeep your problem is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611123/listview-subobject-clickable-confilct

Answer (score 0):

remove Holder)

```
   @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_list_item,
                        parent, false);

            } 

            TextView tv1 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.offer_name);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.expiry_date);
            Button b1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.like_button);

            Button b2 = (Button) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.share_button);
            TextView tvoid = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.offer_id);
            TextView  tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.like);

            final OfferItem it = item.get(position);
            tv1.setText(it.getoffer_name());
            final String message = tv1.getText().toString();
            tv2.setText("Offer ends: " + it.getexpiry_date());
            tvoid.setText(it.getoffer_id());
            tv.setText("Like");
            id_offiers_list.add(it.getoffer_id());

            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String offerid = id_offiers_list.get(position);
                    System.out.println(offerid);
                    if (clicked) {
                        System.out.println(position);
                        b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_icon_hover);                         
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#eaa232"));
                        clicked = false;

                    } else {
                        System.out.println(position);
                        b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_icon);
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#454545"));
                        clicked = true;
                    }
                }
            });

            b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    facebookIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    // facebookIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
                    facebookIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(facebookIntent,
                            "Share..."));
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the boolean clicked inside the OnClickListener. As it is now global, it affects all buttons.

```
holder.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private boolean clicked = false;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String offerid = id_offiers_list.get(position);
            System.out.println(offerid);
            if (clicked) {
                System.out.println(position);
                holder.b1
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_icon_hover);
                holder.tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#eaa232"));
                clicked = false;

            } else {
                System.out.println(position);
                holder.b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_icon);
                holder.tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#454545"));
                clicked = true;
            }
        }
    });
```