# Set a background color to a selected ListView Item programatically

Tags: java, android, listview, layout

There are many questions and answers explaining how to set the background color of a **selected** ListView item by using an adapter and selector.

When an list view item **is selected** I want to define what background color it will have **for the time being selected** and I want to have **different colors** for different items.

Using an `OnItemSelectedListener` did not work, probably doing it at that stage is too late.

Comment: Yoru question is quite unclear, what you want to do exactly?

Comment: Mahoni, it will work, why its not working for you? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Isn't this solution for your problem? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611123/listview-subobject-clickable-confilct/20612237#20612237