# How to use setonitemclicklistener in ANDROID custom Listview Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom listview adapter. I want to include setontemclicklistener  to disable a listitem from the listview.
I've tried using onitemclicklistener but it doesn't work, can you help me out?

Home class:

```
public class Home extends Activity {

JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
ListView listview;
ListViewAdapter adapter;

SharedPreferences pref;
String uid;
static String user_id,us;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

//static String BET_ID = "bet_id";
static String QUESTION = "question";
static String QUES_ID = "ques_id";



@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.questionlist);

uid = pref.getString("user_id",null);
Log.d("uid", ""+uid);



    new DownloadJSON().execute();
}


private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.1.23/MutilatedPHP/QuizGame/quesdownloadjson.php");

        try {

            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("ques");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);


                map.put("question", jsonobject.getString("question"));  
                map.put("ques_id", jsonobject.getString("ques_id"));    



                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(Home.this, arraylist);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
}
```

ListviewAdapter :

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;



HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView qs1;
    TextView qs2;


    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
    }



    resultp = data.get(position);


    qs2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.qs);



    qs2.setText(resultp.get(Home.QUESTION));





    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {



            resultp = data.get(position);


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);


             intent.putExtra("question", resultp.get(Home.QUESTION));
             intent.putExtra("ques_id", resultp.get(Home.QUES_ID));



             context.startActivity(intent);


        }

    });

    return v;

}



}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post some code? How are you disabling your items? How are you setting the listener?

Comment: post your code along with listview xml file.

Comment: what happens when you click on listitem you have `v.setOnClickListener`. Does it not take to `SingleItemView.java`?

Comment: Still don't see where you assign your `OnItemClickListener` you mentioned or where you try to disable `ListItem`

Comment: @Raghunandan : Yes it does but how do i disable an item that is clicked once?

Comment: @LeonidasI You need to store a boolean value somewhere and check the value when the list is displayed and refresh the list. uDo you want it to disabled or hidden when you open the list again?

Comment: @Marius: Okay so how do i disable the listitem using the setonclicklistener present in my adapter

Comment: @Raghunandan : Hidden would be perfect

Comment: @LeonidasI similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611123/listview-subobject-clickable-confilct. When you click the button it turns blue. similarly set the visibility of the view

Comment: Either of these should work, though `setEnabled(false)` will change color too.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled(boolean)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable(boolean)

Answer (score 2):

Try This!

In your `MainActivity` form where the Adapter class is called Add like this:

```
  listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
               int position, long id) {

             // ListView Clicked item index
             int itemPosition     = position;


         }
     });
```

Comment: You mean inside `protected void onPostExecute(Void args)` in the class `Home`?

Comment: no.and that is not compoulsory that you need to set Adapter calss in Async task class.you can set visible true to your list view in onPostExecute() function of your Async task class. And call listView1.setAdapter(adapter);new Task().execute();  lines in your Create() method

Comment: Cool but how do i add the item position here

Comment: in your onItemClick() you will get the int position parameter which will give you the position you tap

Answer (score 2):

You just simple need to call **OnItemClickListener** for ListView.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
            long id) {


    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener();

@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        //Use your code here
    }
```

Comment: should this be used inside the adapter class?

Comment: No MainActivity.java where you have use setAdaptor().

Answer (score 1):

Inside On Create  use this method

```
  listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            Object o = listview.getItemAtPosition(position);

        }
    });
```