# Custom List View; Button click and set text in each row

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a custom List View Adapter. When I click a button in a row, I want to change the text in that same row. However, I am getting an error. When I click on the button in row 0, it changes the text in row 1 or 2 instead (random). Also, do I need to use`setTag();` and `getTag();`

How can I get the button in row 0 to change the text in row 0 when it is clicked.

**Custom List Row Code**

```
public CustomFeedListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
    mContext = context;
    feed = data;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}


  @Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
     position = i;

    View mView = view;


    if (view == null) {


        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_list_row, viewGroup, false);

        feedNumOfLikes = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.feedNumofLikes);
        feedUpVoteButton = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.feedUpVoteButton);
        feedDownVoteButton = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.feedDownVoteButton);

        HashMap<String, String> mFeed = new HashMap<>();
        mFeed = feed.get(i);

       // feedUpVoteButton.setTag(i);
      //  feedNumOfLikes.setTag(i);


        feedUpVoteButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    return mView;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.feedUpVoteButton:

            //v.getTag();

            likes  +=1;
            Log.i("yo", String.valueOf(position));
            feedNumOfLikes.setText(String.valueOf(likes));
            break;

        case R.id.feedDownVoteButton:
            // Do stuff when imageView1 is clicked...

        default:
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611123/listview-subobject-clickable-confilct

Comment: Is there a way to solve my problem with less code/classes involved? @Raghunandan

Comment: less code/classes. What do you mean by that?. What less code are you expecting?? The link i posted is a sample. Modifying is upto you.

Comment: You gave a very good answer on that link. I will find the solution. Thanks @Raghunandan

Comment: @user6868161 try to add the complete code of your CustomFeedListViewAdapter class... then only it may give some idea where you are going wrong..

Comment: @Raghunandan, I figured it out. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @Raghunandan can you please answer my new question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141035/giving-each-row-its-own-int-value-for-custom-list-view